# MySQL Select with Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table in the database: mainTable and classificationTable:

mainTable:

```
id  |   classification_id   |   name
---------------------------------------
1   |           1           |   Name1
2   |           2,3,4       |   Name2
3   |           1,4         |   Name3
4   |           4           |   Name4
```

classificationTable:

```
classification_id   |   class_name
---------------------------------------
        1           |   Class Name1
        2           |   Class Name2
        3           |   Class Name3
        4           |   Class Name4
```

I want to get a select for example for row with ID 3 from mainTable like:

```
id          =   3
class_name  =   Class Name1, Class Name4
Name        =   Name3
```

I try this select, but this return only first elemnt from array (fore exempla for row with ID 3, this return only Class Name1)

```
SELECT i.*, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cl.class_name) FROM classificationTable as cl WHERE cl.classification_id IN(i.classification_id)) as class_name 
FROM mainTable as i;
```

Help PLZ.

Comment: where is classification_name in your table ?

Comment: Sorry, is my mistake. is class_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a poorly designed database.  But you can do what you want.

This requires two steps.  The first is to join the mainTable to the classificationTable by looking for each classification_id in the list in the mainTable.  You can do this using the `like` operator.

The second step is to bring all the class names back into one column.  This is handled using `group_concat`.

The following query accomplishes this (although it is not tested, so it might have a typo):

```
select mt.id, mt.name, group_concat(ct.class_name separator ', ')
from mainTable mt join
     classificationTable ct
     on concat(',', classification_id, ',') like concat('%,', ct.classification_id, ',%')
group by mt.id, mt.name
```

Comment: I understand about classification_id in mainTable. Your solution working perfectly. Thanks for help.

Comment: @AlexandruPara, consider marking this (or another) answer as accepted, your score will go up as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `mainTable`, which not only **violates [the 1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)** but goes even beyond because it concatenates values in the same field (textbook example of a 1NF violation often includes multiple fields, which is bad enough).

The `classification_id` column should not be a concatenation of values but you should have a new table where you have a separate row for each classification_id and it should be tied into mainTable by id.

E.g.

```
id  |   classification_id   
---------------------------------------
1   |           1           
2   |           2           
2   |           3         
2   |           4           
3   |           1       
3   |           4     
4   |           4
```

Once you've done that, your query will be much easier.